# Traverse a directory recursively but stay in the same filesystem

Tags: python, pathlib

If I want to grab everything under a directory, I normally just use `pathlib.Path.rglob()`

However let's assume that `/var/tmp` is actually a different storage device.

How do I recursively traverse `/var` but *only* for contents in the same filesystem/storage device?

Using `rglob()` simply grabs all paths (dirs & files) with no regards to the filesystem.

**Edit:** The OS is Linux; the Python script will be run *only* on Linux, so cross-platform compatibility is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`psutil.disk_partitions`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.disk_partitions) to retrieve all disk partions. The returned value is a namedtuple containing a field `mountpoint`.

When iterating over your desired directory using [`pathlib.Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob), you'll skip the paths of the mounting point that is not a parent of the directory.

```py
import psutil  # pip install psutil

from pathlib import Path

DIRECTORY = "/var"
PATTERN = "*.py"  # let's assume you want to find Python files

disks = psutil.disk_partitions()

mountpoints = tuple(
    disk.mountpoint for disk in disks 
    if not disk.mountpoint in DIRECTORY
)

files = (
    file for file in Path(DIRECTORY).rglob(PATTERN)
    if not str(file).startswith(mountpoints)
)

print(sorted(files))
```

You can also filter the mounting points by devices using the namedtuple's field `device` if needed.

---

Alternatively you could make use of [`pathlib.Path.is_mount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_mount) to detect mounting points:

```py
from pathlib import Path

from typing import Generator

DIRECTORY = "/var"
PATTERN = "*.py"  # let's assume you want to find Python files

def find(directory: str, glob_pattern: str) -> Generator[Path, None, None]:
   
    mountpoints = tuple()

    for file in Path(directory).rglob(glob_pattern):

        if file.is_mount():
            mountpoints = (*mountpoints, str(file))
            continue

        if str(file).startswith(mountpoints):
            continue

        yield file

files = find(DIRECTORY, PATTERN)

print(sorted(files))
```

There is also [`pathlib.Path.is_block_device`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_block_device) if that is more applicable for your use case.